# Visual Studio 2012: Compiler setup (possible to use Compiler from SDK eg. VC++2008-Compiler VC++ 2010-Compiler)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2012

I really like Visual Studio 2012 because the GUI is very fast and flexible. The problem is that i need VC++-Compiler for VS2010. Is it somowhow possible to setup old compilers, SDKs in VS 2012. I really hate the VS 2010-Gui because it's really slow and lagging around.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just modify the platform toolset ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx)):

`Property Pages->Configuration Properties->General`, then click `Platform Toolset` and select the toolset you want. Depending on what you have installed, you should see v90 for MSVC2008 and v100 for MSVC2010.

There is also more detailed info [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! And please excuse me...i'm late